# How can increase the performance in ngx-datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable in my angular project to diplay the data.
data size is 4000+ rows and 50 column.
How can i make it lightweigth becouse page perfomance is too slow.
please suggest me any solution to increase the performance.

I am displaying the data in angular ngx-datatable that data size is more than 3000 rows
I want to increase the performance.

Comment: I have filter based on full data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance using virtual scrolling, that would help you out:
[Virtual Scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling)

As in Hyperlink mentioned: "Virtual-Scroll displays large lists of elements performantly by only rendering the items that fit on-screen"